# Retrive date from db(sqlite) and post it in listview in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I've stored future date, event name in db(sqlite)

I am retrieving date,events from db and post it using listview.

How can I calculate days left from date which is retrieving from db and current date.?

Then, I need to display Events, and total days left in list view.

So the methods are :

DatabaseHelperClass.cs

```
public DaysLeft ReadDaysLeft(int daysid)
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_Path))
        {
            var data = dbConn.Query<DaysLeft>("select * from DaysLeft where Id = " + daysid).FirstOrDefault();
             System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("In ReadDaysLeft"+data);
            return data;
        }

    }


public ObservableCollection<DaysLeft> ReadDaysLeft()
    {
        using (var dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_Path)) 
        {

            List<DaysLeft> mycollection = dbConn.Table<DaysLeft>().ToList<DaysLeft>();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("In ReadDaysLeftCollection"+mycollection);

            ObservableCollection<DaysLeft> dayslist = new ObservableCollection<DaysLeft>(mycollection);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("In ReadDaysLeftCollection" + dayslist);
            return dayslist;

        }
    }
```

ReadALLData.cs

```
 public class ReadAllData
 {
    DatabaseHelperClass dbHelper = new DatabaseHelperClass();
    public ObservableCollection<DaysLeft> GetAllDays()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("In GetAllDays");
        return dbHelper.ReadDaysLeft();
    }
}
```

BasicPage.cs

```
  private void AddDataToListView(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReadAllData alldata = new ReadAllData();
        DB_DaysLeft = alldata.GetAllDays();     

        DaysLeftListView.ItemsSource = DB_DaysLeft.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();


    }
```

I've edited according to your suggestions.. Added to two objects like

```
 List<int> daysleft { get; set; }
    string events;

 private void AddDataToListView(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        daysleft = new List<int>();

        ReadAllData alldata = new ReadAllData();
        DB_DaysLeft = alldata.GetAllDays();
        foreach (var Date in DB_DaysLeft)
        {
            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(Date);

            TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now - Date.Date;
            int days = (int)Math.Abs(Math.Round(diff.TotalDays));


           //TimeSpan durations= DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).TotalDays();
            daysleft.Add(days);
        }
        DaysLeftListView.ItemsSource = DB_DaysLeft.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();


    }
```

In BasicPage1.cs

```
     private void DaysLeftListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int Select_Changed = 0;
        if (DaysLeftListView.SelectedIndex !=-1)
        {
            tempclass selectedDay = DaysLeftListView.SelectedItem as tempclass;
            Frame.Navigate(typeof(EditWindow), Select_Changed = selectedDay.id);
        }
    }
```

EditOrUpdateWindow.cs

```
   //from previous page
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Selected_DaysId = Int32.Parse(e.Parameter.ToString());
        daysleft = dbHelp.ReadDaysLeftForEdit(Selected_DaysId);
        var temp_date = daysleft.diff;
        event_date.Date = DateTimeOffset.Parse(daysleft.diff.ToString());
        event_text.Text =   daysleft.myEvent;
       // this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }        




    //To Save into db.
    private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dayleftOfDaysLeft.Date = DateTime.Parse(event_date.Date.ToString());
        dayleftOfDaysLeft.Events = event_text.Text;
        dbHelp.UpdateDays(dayleftOfDaysLeft);
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(BasicPage1));

    }
```

Please help me . Thank you.

Comment: which db you are using? if sqllite then use (strftime('%s','2011-05-12 01:03:00') - strftime('%s','2011-05-08 11:54:09')) for date difference

Comment: Yeah. I am using SQLite db.

Comment: use query like this                                                                                  SELECT julianday('now') - julianday(DateCreated) FROM Table                               ref:-http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: OK thank you.. If I write above query, where I have to store it? In an separate column?.. I'm confused. or should I need to store current date also in db?

Comment: don't store it give them Aliase for eg:- SELECT (julianday('now') - julianday(DateCreated)) as DaysLeft FROM Table and access it as column DaysLeft

Comment: okay fine.. How to access Aliase as column..? Please explain.

Comment: don't confuse make your query as it will give result as date,events,DaysLeft so you can directly bind your result to view

Comment: Okay.. the query will be SELECT (julianday('Fut_Evnt_Date') - julianday('now')) as DaysLeft , Fut_Evnt_Date, Event from tablename where id= "+id .. Is the syntax is correct ?

Comment: I've edited the question..please check the code.. thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes like this:

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
DateTime date2 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
int diff = date2.Subtract(date1).TotalDays();
```

for binding it to windows phone 8.1 you need to do like that:

In your .cs file:

```
public class AllData
{
   public int diff { get; set; }
   public string myEvent {get;set;}
}

public class RootObject
{
  public List<AllData> dataFromDb { get; set; }
  //all your other code
}
```

In the xaml:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding dataFromDb }">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding diff}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding myEvent}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="18" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And also if you haven't done it already, you need to set the DataContext for the page after you downloaded the data, like this (assuming you do the downloading in the code-behind file of a page, e.g. MainPage.xaml.cs):

```
RootObject json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(await serverData);
this.DataContext = json;
```

So specific to your code this is how you suppose to do it:

```
public class AllData
{
   public int diff { get; set; }
   public string myEvent {get;set;}
}

public class YourClass{
         List<AllData> daysLeft {get; set;}

         private void AddDataToListView(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                daysleft = new List<AllData>();

                ReadAllData alldata = new ReadAllData();
                DB_DaysLeft = alldata.GetAllDays();
                foreach (var Date in DB_DaysLeft)
                {
                    AllData ad = new AllData();
                    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(Date);

                    TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now - Date.Date;
                    int days = (int)Math.Abs(Math.Round(diff.TotalDays));


                   ad.diff = days;
                   ad.myEvent = events;
                    daysleft.Add(ad);
                }
                DaysLeftListView.ItemsSource = DB_DaysLeft.OrderByDescending(i => i.Id).ToList();

     }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78311/discussion-on-answer-by-israel-altar-retrive-date-from-dbsqlite-and-post-it-in).

Comment: One more issue buddy.. when I click on the item in list.. it gives null pointer exception in another page..I got the days left count in a listview.. I've written the code to ,when a user click on any list item it should passess to next windows to display what he has selected.SO when i pass to next page.. it shows an null pointer exception

Comment: Uploaded the code.. Please check.. I need to pass the selected item's date of event to next page in date picker. So that user can update it

Comment: 1) check if  after event_date.Date = DateTimeOffset.Parse(daysleft.diff.ToString()); the event_date != null 2) we should continue the discussion in the chat (i see you have enough reputation for using it. the only problem is that i can use the chat when i'm home, so if i don't answer for some hours it because of that :-)

Comment: OKay. .I've asked my doubts in chat.. Please check